# Low events Calendar conditional

Tags: low-events

Is there a conditional for {exp:low_events:calendar} for passed days, so for example if the day is in the past add a class?

```
{if passed}class="passed"{/if}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jrothafer, you're thinking of Low Events, not Low Calendar (which doesn't exist). Should be no reason to bring Low Nice Date into things.

The `{if passed}` conditional is not supported in the low_events:calendar tag. But you might be able to compose a conditional using the `{day_url}` and `{current_date}` variables.

Comment: Lol, sorry Low! That's what I get for trying to answer questions before my morning 7 cups of coffee. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: Cheers Low, worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Cheif, you should peruse your third-party vendors a little more carefully.

http://gotolow.com/addons/low-nice-date/docs

```
{exp:low_nice_date:range from="{date_one}" to="{date_two}"}
    {if days == 0}
        The two dates are on the same day
    {if:else}
        The two dates span {days} days
    {/if}
{/exp:low_nice_date:range}
```

That one is completely free, and since it's the same vendor, seems like it should be about 100% compatible with Low Events.